Creating a xcframework with both Debug and Release libs?
I'm building a library, and my goal is to provide a way for users to automatically get the right version depending on their configuration (Debug or Release).
I used to do that with .a files, where, in their project, I'd set Linker Flags to -lMyLib1 -lMyLib2 ... and then set the Library Search Path to a different value for Debug and Release (two directories with the .a files compiled for Debug and Release respectively).
Now I am switching to xcframeworks, but I find no way to do that. Should I bundle my release and debug libs together in the xcframework? Is that even possible? If not, how can I make xcode pick a different xcframework depending on the configuration, in my app? Am I missing something obvious here?
